# How can I set default parameter value in routing in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

How can I set default parameter value in routing in Rails 3.
For example I have this route

```
match ':slug/:id/:direction' => 'quiz#show', :as => :quiz_details, :direction => "next"
```

and I want to default the value of direction to `next`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

```
match ':slug/:id/:direction' => 'quiz#show', :as => :quiz_details, :defaults => { :direction => "next" }
```

More details in the [official Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults).

Comment: it's possible to do the same for resources: `resources :user, defaults: { id: 1 }`