# Rails 4 path alias for Individual Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on rails 4 project

Is there any possibility to create path alias for the individual resources

(eg)
   articles/1 => "about" 
   articles/2 => "products"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can route paths to controller actions and provide default parameters. It would be:

```
get '/about', to: 'articles#show', defaults: { id: 1 }
get '/products', to: 'articles#show', defaults: { id: 2 }
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240003/how-can-i-set-default-parameter-value-in-routing-in-rails-3)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
match 'articles/1' :to 'controller#about'
match 'articles/2' :to 'controller#about'
```

where the controller can be something like users