# What does default: { action: 'method' } do in rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I came across line:

```
resources :assesments, default: {action: :index }
```

inside rails routes.

`rake routes` for `resources :assesments` prints:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    assesments GET    /assesments(.:format)          assesments#index
               POST   /assesments(.:format)          assesments#create
 new_assesment GET    /assesments/new(.:format)      assesments#new
edit_assesment GET    /assesments/:id/edit(.:format) assesments#edit
     assesment GET    /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#show
               PATCH  /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#update
               PUT    /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#update
               DELETE /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#destroy
```

and for `default: { action: :index}` it prints:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    assesments GET    /assesments(.:format)          assesments#index {:default=>{:action=>:index}}
               POST   /assesments(.:format)          assesments#create {:default=>{:action=>:index}}
 new_assesment GET    /assesments/new(.:format)      assesments#new {:default=>{:action=>:index}}
edit_assesment GET    /assesments/:id/edit(.:format) assesments#edit {:default=>{:action=>:index}}
     assesment GET    /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#show {:default=>{:action=>:index}}
               PATCH  /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#update {:default=>{:action=>:index}}
               PUT    /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#update {:default=>{:action=>:index}}
               DELETE /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#destroy {:default=>{:action=>:index}}
```

what does default action change?

### edit

I made a typo. It should be:

`resources :assesments, defaults: {action: :index }`

and `rake routes` looks normally now:

```
        Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
    assesments GET    /assesments(.:format)          assesments#index
               POST   /assesments(.:format)          assesments#create
 new_assesment GET    /assesments/new(.:format)      assesments#new
edit_assesment GET    /assesments/:id/edit(.:format) assesments#edit
     assesment GET    /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#show
               PATCH  /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#update
               PUT    /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#update
               DELETE /assesments/:id(.:format)      assesments#destroy
```

Comment: I don't see any option called `default` -> [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Resources.html#method-i-resources)

Comment: It doesn't do anything.

Comment: But, I see the option in [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#defining-defaults).

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7240003/how-can-i-set-default-parameter-value-in-routing-in-rails-3) will tell you, what that option generally do.

Comment: In this case it will probably just set `params[:action]` to `:index` for all routes.

Comment: @EgonWilzer I think that option will not be helpful with `resources`, but it is helpful while you are creating some dynamic routes.

Comment: `default` tells routes which action to use if none is specified.  `index` is the standard default, so setting "default: index" won't make any difference, as it would have defaulted to index anyway.

Comment: I found this piece of code at the end of http://blog.crowdint.com/2010/11/05/controller-responders-in-rails-3.html

Comment: Oh jesus, I made a typo... `default:` -> `defaults:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

if we would have

`resources :assesments, defaults: { format: 'jpg' }, default: { format: 'xml'}`

and we would visit `localhost/assessments` than `params` hash would look like:

```
{
 "format"=>"jpg", # FROM defaults: {}
 "default"=> { "format"=>"xml" }, # FROM default: {}
 "controller"=>"assesments", WE CAN NOT CHANGE IT. COMES FROM RAILS
 "action"=>"index" # WE CAN NOT CHANGE IT. COMES FROM RAILS
}
```

### --- more

`defaults: { anything_key: 'any_value' }` will add hash content to `params` hash accessible inside controller (however you can not override values provided by controller - that is: `:action` and `:controller`).

Adding `defaults: { action: :anything }` will not have any effect but adding `defaults: { format: 'jpg' }` will add `{ format: 'jpg' }` to `params` hash inside all controllers wrapped by routing scope.

Adding `default: { some_key: 'value' }` will add this hash (`default: { some_key: 'value' }`) to every params hash inside controllers wrapped by routing scope.